# Calculating the times into minutes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on my python code as I want to calulcating on the program time to convert it into minutes. When the program start at `12:00AM` and my current time show as `1:00AM`. The end time show for the program is `6:00AM`, so I want to work out between `1:00AM` and `6:00AM` to take it away then multiply it by 60 to convert it into minutes.

Example: `6` take away `1` which is `5` then I want to multply it by 60 which it is 300 minutes.

Here is the code:

```
current_time = int(time.strftime("%M"))
prog_width = self.getControl(int(program_id)).getWidth()
prog_length = int(prog_width) / 11.4 - current_time
prog_length = str(prog_length)
prog_length = prog_length.replace('.0', '')
prog_length = int(prog_length)
print prog_length
```

Can you please show me an example of how I can calculating between `1:00AM` and `6:00AM` to take it away then convert it into minutes when multply by 60?

Comment: does anyone know how  I can calculating the time between `1:00AM` and `6:00AM` to take it away then multply by 60 to convert it into minutes?

Comment: I don't see how the code you show has anything to do with the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module

```
from datetime import timedelta

start = timedelta(hours=1)
end = timedelta(hours=6)
duration = end - start
print duration.total_seconds() / 60
```